# How to unit test methods relying on an App instance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms

I have a method `LoadItems()` in my `ItemsViewModel` that should populate a property of the view model with items from an SQLite database.

How can I unit test this method to make sure my Items property is correctly updated with the content from the database?

I figure I have to mock the database somehow but I can't figure out how to do it without rewriting the `LoadItems()` method itself.

```
public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel() { ... }

    void LoadItems()
    {
        Items.Clear();
        var items = App.Database.GetItems();
        foreach (var item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is what Dependency Injection is all about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection): don't use `static` members of other types for external services like IO (databases, etc).

(And your database operations should be `async`)

Change your class to this:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IDatabase db;

    public ItemsViewModel( IDatabase database )
    {
        this.db = database ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(database));

        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

    public async Task LoadItemsAsync()
    {
        // (Show an activity indicator here and disable other inputs)

        this.Items.Clear();
        var items = await this.db.GetItemsAsync();
        this.Items.AddRange( items );

        // (Hide the activity indicator here)
    }
}
```

And register your database in your DI container:

(I assume you're using a `ViewModelLocator` - though many consider this to be an anti-pattern):

```
public static class MyViewModelLocator
{
    private static readonly IContainer _container = RegisterDependencies();

    private static IContainer RegisterDependencies()
    {
        return new ContainerBuilder()
            // Register services (this is required):
            .RegisterType<IDatabase,MyDatabase>()
            // Register consumers (this is optional and only needed if you're using the ViewModelLocator pattern in your XAML views):
            .RegisterSingleton<ItemsViewModel>()
            .Build();
    }

    public static IContainer Container => _container;

    public static ItemsViewModel ItemsViewModel => _container.Resolve<ItemsViewModel();
}
```

Then to test it, you provide your own `IDatabase` either created for the test or as an `IClassFixture` without using the `MyViewModelLocator` (note that xUnit's `IClassFixture` is not the same thing as DI):

```
public class ItemsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Load_items_passes_the_ronseal_challenge()
    {
        using( IDatabase testDatabase = new FakeDatabase() )
        {
            ItemsViewModel vm = new ItemsViewModel( db );

            Assert.Equal( 0, vm.Items.Count );

            await vm.LoadItemsAsync();

            Assert.Equal( 5, vm.Items.Count );
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
public class ItemsTests : IClassFixture<IDatabase>
{
    private readonly IDatabase db;

    public ItemsTests( IDatabase db )
    {
        this.db = db ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(db));
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Load_items_passes_the_ronseal_challenge()
    {
        ItemsViewModel vm = new ItemsViewModel( this.db );

        Assert.Equal( 0, vm.Items.Count );

        await vm.LoadItemsAsync();

        Assert.Equal( 5, vm.Items.Count );
    }
}
```